# grep and sed in a Fortran Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran code that can be compiled by the following Makefile:

```
FC = mpif90  
FFLAGS := ...

TARGET = run1

SRC = main.f90 param.f90 ...
OBJ = $(SRC:.f90=.o)

all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJ) $(FC) $(FFLAGS)
...
```

In the above, the **TARGET** can be *run1* or *run2* or *run3*, depending on the value of a variable in my script. For example, if I have the following in param.f90:

```
character(len=1), parameter :: case_num = "1"
```

Then, I want the TARGET variable to be set as *run1*. Now, the question is how to do that automatically without manually changing the Makefile every time?

I have tried something like

```
num = $(grep 'case_num = "' param.f90 | sed -n -e 's/^.*case_num = "//p' | cut -c1-1)
TARGET = run$num
```

in the Makefile, which doesn't work. I have checked that the grep and sed sentence is correct in a regular bash script. How to do this in a Fortran Makefile? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With GNU Make use: `num = $(shell grep ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile appears to a GNU Make makefile. To assign the output of a
shell command to a make variable, you need to use the [`$(shell ...)` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html),
like:

```
num := $(shell grep 'case_num = "' param.f90 | sed -n -e 's/^.*case_num = "//p' | cut -c1-1)
TARGET := run$(num)
```